# Appending to file not showing up on logstash or elasticsearch output

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, input, logstash, elastic-stack

I spun up logstash and elasticsearch docker containers using images from elastic.co. When I append to the file which I have set as my input file I don't see any output from logstash or elasticsearch. This [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) didn't help much and couldn't find my exact problem on google or stackoverflow.

This is how I started my containers:

```
docker run                      \
--name elasticsearch            \
-p 9200:9200                    \
-p 9300:9300                    \
-e "discovery.type=single-node" \
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.1


docker run \
--name logstash \
--rm -it -v $(pwd)/elk/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml \
-v $(pwd)/elk/pipeline.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/pipeline.conf \
docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.3.1
```

This is my pipeline configuration file:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/pepper/logstash-tutorial.log"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://x.x.x.x:9200/"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```

Logstash and elasticsearch started fine it seems.
Sample logstash startup output:

```
[INFO ][logstash.inputs.beats    ] Beats inputs: Starting input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5044"}
[INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x6dc306e7 sleep>"}
[INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>2, :running_pipelines=>[:main, :".monitoring-logstash"], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[INFO ][org.logstash.beats.Server] Starting server on port: 5044
[INFO ][logstash.inputs.metrics  ] Monitoring License OK
[INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

Sample elasticsearch startup output:

```
[INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [FJImg8Z] Cluster health status changed from [YELLOW] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.monitoring-logstash-6-2018.07.10][0]] ...]).
```

So when I make changes to logstash-tutorial.log, I don't see any terminal output from logstash or elasticsearch. How to get output or configure logstash and elasticsearch correctly?

Comment: How did you resolve it finally. I encounter the same problem

Comment: @user2256235 you could probably make it work if you don't use containerisation. We ended up moving to Elasticsearch Service on AWS and picking up logs using Kinesis Firehose. Way less effort. ELK requires a lot of setup but ofcourse ELK is cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on the same page that you have referred. Take a look at [start_position](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-start_position)

> Choose where Logstash starts initially reading files: at the beginning or at the end. The **default behavior treats files like live streams and thus starts at the end**. If you have old data you want to import, ***set this to beginning***.

Set the start position as below:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/pepper/logstash-tutorial.log"
    start_position => "beginning" 
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://x.x.x.x:9200/"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => "rubydebug"
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, adding `start_position => "beginning"` didn't change anything. I also tried waiting a bit as it can be a bit slow sometimes. I also tried adding `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` but still nothing. It might be something to do with it running on a vagrant machine. I will try running it on my mac and see if it works.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working on mac either. Any ideas?

Comment: Only other thing is it will keep reading the file indefinitely so u have to stop the logstash process. Also, Try refreshing elastic and see if the data is indexed. Other than that I have no idea about system specific issue. Above code works for me  on windows.